# casting then dereferencing pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

When working with `char` buffers in C, sometimes it would be useful and more efficient to able to work with `int`-sized chunks of data at a time. To do this I can cast my `char *` to an `int *` and use that pointer instead. However I'm not entirely confident that this works the way I think it does.

For example, suppose I have `char *data`, does `*(int32_t *)data = -1` always overwrite the bytes `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` and `data[3]` and no other bytes?

Comment: I think that also violates strict-aliasing. You're allowed to alias any datatype with `char*`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work as you expected? Also, when setting a buffer to a number it is normally better to use functions such as `memset` as they are already optimized with techniques similar to this.

Comment: You should use an `union` instead. Example: `union { int data; char buffer[sizeof(int)]; };`. Also pay attention to endianness and alignment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, trying a particular case on a particular system is not a great way of learning about undefined behavior.

Comment: @jweyrich Surprisingly, type-punning through a union like that also has undefined results and sometimes if you write through `data` then a subsequent read from `buffer` might not give you the right result. That burned me once on a particular compiler. You need to use memcpy instead. (Yes, it's weird -- it always worked fine for us in MSVC but then the code mysteriously blew up when using an esoteric vendor-supplied compiler.)

Comment: @Crashworks: writing to a member of a union, and reading from another is UB. One should only read from the last written member.

Comment: @Crashworks, jweyrich: C99 explicitly allows type-punning through unions - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8513748/48015

Comment: @Christoph: oh, how did I miss that for so long? TYVM! :)

Comment: @Christoph That makes me even more sad that [HARDWARE MANUFACTURER] still hasn't caught up with their compiler. =(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.

**There are two major issues here:**

- It violates [strict-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/922184).
- You might break alignment.

---

Violating strict-aliasing is technically **undefined behavior**. You are allowed to alias any datatype with `char*`, but not the other way around.

You can get around the issue with `f[no-]strict-aliasing` on GCC.

---

The other issue is alignment. The `char` pointer might not be properly aligned. Accessing misaligned data may lead to performance degradation or even a hardware exception if the hardware doesn't support misaligned access.

---

If performance isn't an issue, the full-proof way is to `memcpy()` to an `int` array buffer.

Once these two issues are resolved, your example with:

```
*(int32_t *)data = -1
```

overwriting `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]`, and `data[3]` should work as expected if `sizeof(int32_t) == 4`. Just pay attention to the endianness...

Comment: I think you hit the right points, perhaps missing the question of what value is actually put there. @Shum might be expecting all bytes to get the value -1, which will happen in a normal system, for the specific case of -1, but is certainly not guaranteed in general.

Comment: @Crashworks, If you can't disable strict-aliasing, then it gets tricky... :( This is a common problem that I actually ignore when vectorizing. (eg. `__m128d*` will alias with `double*`)

Comment: @Crashworks: if performance is an issue, then you might consider non-portable solutions. For example, with GCC you might go ahead with type punning and use the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option (that's what the Linux kernel does).  Or - again with GCC - you could choose to use the union 'workaround', which GCC explicitly supports, even when `-fstrict-aliasing` is in force.  But, you need to realize that these workarounds are not portable.

Answer (score 3):

This is technically undefined behavior and the standard is silent on the results of aliasing pointers like this. A standards pedant would say that invoking undefined behavior in this way could result in anything from corrupted data to a system crash to Ragnarok.

Pragmatically, this depends on your hardware. Most modern systems (eg x86, x64, PPC, MIPS, ARM)  handle word-sized writes in the way you describe, with the exception that writing to an unaligned address will result in a crash. Also, this is when endianness comes into play; on a little endian system

```
char foo[4];
*((uint_32*)(foo)) = 0x01020304;
// the following are now true:
foo[0] == 0x04;
foo[1] == 0x03;
foo[2] == 0x02;
foo[3] == 0x01;
```

The short answer is that this isn't safe unless you know exactly what hardware your program will run on.

If you *do* control the hardware you compile for, then you can predict what the compiler will do; I've used this trick to speed up packing of byte arrays on embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily. If the data isn't aligned correctly, it might not work at all. Assuming it's aligned correctly, it'll probably overwrite the next `sizeof(int)` bytes and nothing else, but I'm not sure even that much is entirely guaranteed.

Comment: *If the data isn't aligned correctly* > can you please tell me what is alignment and why is it mostly related to types etc? , is it have to do with endianess?

Comment: Alignment is mostly a hardware artifact. For example, a lot of hardware requires that when you load a 32-bit value that it be aligned to a value that's a multiple of 4 bytes -- i.e., that the 3 least significant bits of the address are all zeros. Other hardware doesn't require that, but still gains performance when it's true.

Comment: Just a minor correction: alignment to 4 bytes means the 2 least significant bits are zero. 3 bits would indicate unsigned values from 0 to 7, right? =)